# Is it better to put the *ngFor directive in the mat-select tag or mat-option tag?

Tags: angular

Consider the two different ways to generate a mat-select dropdown display with multiple options from an array (in this case `optionList`) in the `.ts` file.

**something.component.html**

```
<!-- Place the *ngFor in mat-select-->
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Dropdown</mat-label>
  <mat-select *ngFor="let option of optionList;"  [(value)]="selectedOption">
    <mat-option [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- Place the *ngFor in mat-option -->
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Dropdown</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedOption">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of optionList;" [value]="option">
      {{option}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Both html-blocks appear to have the exact same functionality.** So, is there a better/standard way of doing things? **Does one have some advantage over the other?**

Thanks

Comment: Why would you not just use the 2nd one which is closest to examples on material website?

Comment: The first one repeats the entire select list over and over.

Answer (score 1):

**Both HTML blocks appear to have the exact same functionality**

No, they do not have the same functionality. The first one repeats the entire `select` which will lead to multiple dropdowns within the `mat-form-field`. You need only the `option` elements to be repeated so the second one is the way to go.

**Does one have some advantage over the other?**

Well clearly from the above point we can conclude that the second one works and the first one doesn't.

Just plug those HTML blocks into a simple [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and assign an array to `optionList` and you will see that the first one does not work as expected and produces a weird result.

[image: incorrect select dropdown]

Four `select` elements get created since I used `optionList` of length 4.

**Conclusion**

Use the second HTML block and check out the [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) docs.